# Opposite of .gzuncompress(base64_decode(

Tags: php

I've seen a person use .gzuncompress(base64_decode( to protect their code from being leaked. I was just wondering what the opposite of .gzuncompress(base64_decode( is so I can also do this. Everytime I gzcompress a base64 string i get unusable chars whereas the string in this persons script doesn't do that so I know i'm doing something wrong.

A point in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: This really doesn't protect anything. Any developer with half a bit of experience would find it out.

Comment: How would I go about compressing a whole script using it though?

Answer (score 2):

```
base64_encode(gzcompress($foo))
```

Comment: Thanks, how would I go about compressing a whole php file using that command?

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = base64_encode(gzcompress("Hello World"));
echo gzuncompress(base64_decode($data)); // Hello World
```